# Get column object from string name

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I wrote a column documenting code has been updated in the table using trigger

```
insert into dbo.LogTable([Contrnt])
select 
i.COLUMN_NAME + 'is update!'
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS i
    where UPDATE (answer) and  i.TABLE_NAME='Questions'
```

But this code is not efficient because I want to go through all the columns and what revised will log like this:

```
    insert into dbo.LogTable([Contrnt])
select 
i.COLUMN_NAME + 'is update!'
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS i
    where UPDATE (i.COLUMN_NAME) and  i.TABLE_NAME='Questions'
```

Now since the return value from: `i.COLUMN_NAME` is a string and the function UPDATE does not get it generated an error.
What is the way to solve it get to represent the object through the name

Answer (score -1):

You can build a query script as a string using prints, This way you can generate all scripts for all your columns with a loop, and copy past it in your trigger